# How can a child component find if the Parent Component is finished modifying the dom, from it's recieved props

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am working on a library project.
My root component is listening to the redux store. on my initial page visit, the store is not loaded. so it shows no books at first. after about in 1 second (after the books API call finishes) it loads books to the redux store which updates the Dom of the root container with fetched books.

I have a menuBar component which works as a child component of the root component. is getting dom nodes created by the root object [ I use document.getElementByID('ID') ]. I do this in my child components componentDidMount() function. the problem is child Component doesn't rerender after root component rerenders.

so menubar stays empty.

I use redux-persist.
If I refresh the page, the menubar will appear because redux-persist gives values to the redux store from the initial API fetch.

Is there a way to detect if a root component is doing a dom modification and If so is there a way to force update the child Component from the root component.

please comment if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the data to the child component rather than using a ID lookup.

```js
const Parent = (store) => {
    
  const dataFromRedux = store.parentData
  // get your data some how

  return (
  <div>
    <Child data={dataFromRedux} />
  <div>
  )
}

const Child = ({ data }) => {
  // child will now re-render when the data is updated
  return <div>{data}</div>
}
```